# How to set a property to an object that defined in vue js data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, prototype

I'm tring to set a property to an empty object that defined in data by using prototype, but I got an error that the object is undefined, I see error just when using "prototype", what I had to do?

this is for vue@2.6.10 also vue-router@3.1.3 and vuex@3.1.1 are used.
The below code is part of a component that imported in another.

```
<template>
  <input class="input" v-model="RealName" placeholder="Your Name"/>
  ...
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Person",
  data() {
    return {
      Email: null,
      RealName: null,
      Ncode: null,
      City: null,
      Education: null,
      Phone: null,
      static: {}
    }
  },
  watch: {
    RealName: function(changed, lastOne){

      this.static.prototype.firstRealName = this.static.firstRealName | lastOne // -- Ttrouble -- 

      console.log(this.static.firstRealName + ': ' + lastOne +' => ' + changed)
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

When I edit the input I got this error on console:
“TypeError: Cannot set property 'firstRealName' of undefined ...”

Comment: What is this.static.prototype?
`watch: {
    'RealName': function(curr, prev){
      this.static.prototype.firstRealName = this.static.firstRealName | prev // -- Ttrouble -- 
      console.log(this.static.firstRealName + ': ' + prev +' => ' + curr)
    }
  }`

Comment: @Omer It keeps the first value of any variable that changes at least one time

Comment: `this.static.prototype` is undefined, so you can't do `this.static.prototype.firstRealName`.

Comment: @DecadeMoon Yep, but why? normally it must add the property of "firstRealName" to the Object "static". also if you check this you can see `this.static` is defined: `console.log(this.static)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
this.static.prototype.firstRealName = this.static.firstRealName | lastOne
```

you can use

```
this.$set(this.static, "firstRealName", this.static.firstRealName | lastOne);
```

docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats)

Answer (score 0):

`this.static.prototype` is undefined. You have initialized `static` to the empty object `{}` which has no such `prototype` property defined on it. Therefore you can't do `this.static.prototype.firstRealName`.

```
this.static.prototype.firstRealName = this.static.firstRealName
            ^                                     ^
            undefined                             undefined
```

Accessing an undefined property of an object is fine, as in `this.static.firstRealName`, however you cannot access a property of an `undefined` object as in `this.static.prototype.firstRealName`. You can't access property `firstRealName` of an undefined object (`prototype`).

You need to define the properties up front:

```
data() {
  return {
    Email: null,
    RealName: null,
    Ncode: null,
    City: null,
    Education: null,
    Phone: null,
    static: {
      prototype: {}  // need to define it up front
    }
  };
},
```

Keep in mind the [change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties) in Vue.